# How do you split XMLs in mule? splitter?

Tags: xslt, mule, splitter

Im a bit new to splitting XMLs, Can you help me create multiple XMLs from one input? do I need to use splitters? XSLT? also, can i plud in the message id in the xml as well?

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StockMovementDataRequest xmlns:p1="urn:ams.com.au:dynamo:3pl:am:SAP_AM_I_005:StockMovement" xmlns:a="http://www.edi.com.au/EnterpriseService">
    <Header>
        <From>Warehouse</From>
        <To>Location</To>
        <Unique_ID>idm1468201212</Unique_ID>
        <DateTimeStamp>2016-04-13T11:55:30.263+10:00</DateTimeStamp>
    </Header>
    <StockMovementData>
        <Serialised_Material>YES</Serialised_Material>
        <DateTime>2016-04-13T11:55:30.263+10:00</DateTime>
        <From_Location>30-80</From_Location>
        <To_Location>client</To_Location>
        <Material>7CAGL3G00</Material>
        <Serial>700030011</Serial>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
    </StockMovementData>
    <StockMovementData>
        <Serialised_Material>YES</Serialised_Material>
        <DateTime>2016-04-13T11:55:30.263+10:00</DateTime>
        <From_Location>30-80</From_Location>
        <To_Location>client</To_Location>
        <Material>7CAGL3G00</Material>
        <Serial>700029911</Serial>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
    </StockMovementData>
</StockMovementDataRequest>
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StockMovementDataRequest xmlns:p1="urn:ams.com.au:dynamo:3pl:am:SAP_AM_I_005:StockMovement"
    xmlns:a="http://www.edi.com.au/EnterpriseService/">
    <Header>
        <From>warehouse</From>
        <To>client</To>
        <Unique_ID>idm1467386212</Unique_ID>
        <DateTimeStamp>2016-04-13T11:55:30.263+10:00</DateTimeStamp>
    </Header>
    <StockMovementData>
        <Serialised_Material>YES</Serialised_Material>
        <DateTime>2016-04-13T11:55:30.263+10:00</DateTime>
        <From_Location>30-80</From_Location>
        <To_Location>client</To_Location>
        <Material>7CAGL3G00</Material>
        <Serial>700030011</Serial>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
    </StockMovementData>
</StockMovementDataRequest>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StockMovementDataRequest xmlns:p1="urn:ams.com.au:dynamo:3pl:am:SAP_AM_I_005:StockMovement"
    xmlns:a="http://www.edi.com.au/EnterpriseService/">
    <Header>
        <From>warehouse</From>
        <To>client</To>
        <Unique_ID>idm1467386212</Unique_ID>
        <DateTimeStamp>2016-04-13T11:55:30.263+10:00</DateTimeStamp>
    </Header>
    <StockMovementData>
        <Serialised_Material>YES</Serialised_Material>
        <DateTime>2016-04-13T11:55:30.263+10:00</DateTime>
        <From_Location>30-80</From_Location>
        <To_Location>client</To_Location>
        <Material>7CAGL3G00</Material>
        <Serial>700029911</Serial>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
    </StockMovementData>
</StockMovementDataRequest>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: is `StockMovementDataRequest` your root node? If not, then your XML is malformed.

Comment: Hi Joel, Thanks for noticing that I missed it when I was copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Mule Splitter` to split `xml`

```
    <splitter expression="#[xpath3('//StockMovementDataRequest/StockMovementData',payload,'NODESET')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>        
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
```

To aggregate the payload after splitter, use `aggregator`

```
<collection-aggregator doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
```

See more documentation here
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/splitter-flow-control-reference

Answer (score 1):

If your processor supports XSLT-2.0, you can try the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="StockMovementDataRequest/StockMovementData">
            <xsl:result-document href="{concat('output', position(), '.xml')}">
                <StockMovementDataRequest xmlns:p1="urn:ams.com.au:dynamo:3pl:am:SAP_AM_I_005:StockMovement" xmlns:a="http://www.edi.com.au/EnterpriseService">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::Header"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </StockMovementDataRequest>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it outputs, output1.xml and output2.xml based on your input.